# Edit the selected value in a drop box in angular js

Tags: angularjs

I have created a database with variable types and name. I want to edit the type and save it again. I have used a drop box to get the type. When editing the type I want the current type  to show. How I can do this with angularjs? Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Yes. like this  <option ng-model="selected">{{selected}}</option>. But the selected type is coming two times.

Comment: Edit your question and post all the relevant code. That way we can try to identify how to solve your exact problem. HTML, controller, data service etc